# ruby on rails convert cp1251 to utf8

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, cp1251

I'm using remote server request to get geodata

```
@xml = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip=144.206.192.6")).body
```

The server response comes in cp1251, how to convert it to uft-8?